# CakePHP w CakeDC users plugin with external database: Call to a member function user() on boolean

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, cakephp-3.x, cakedc

My app is developed in CakePHP 3.x, and has 2 databases.

I use CakedDC Users plugin, and it works fine with all models from the default database. Here is what I have in AppController:

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();

    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler', [
        'viewClassMap' => [
            'docx' => 'Word',
        ],
    ]);
    $this->loadComponent('Paginator');
    $this->loadComponent('CakeDC/Users.UsersAuth');
}

public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
$userId = $this->Auth->user('id');
    EventManager::instance()->on(new RequestMetadata($this->request, $userId));
    $isLogged = $this->Auth->user();
    $this->set(compact('isLogged'));

    if ($clientId = $this->request->query('client_id')) {
        $client = $this->loadModel('Clients')->find()
            ->where(['id' => $clientId])
            ->select(['id', 'slug', 'last_name', 'first_name'])
            ->first();

        $this->set(compact('client'));
    }
}

public function beforeRender(Event $event)
{
    if (!array_key_exists('_serialize', $this->viewVars) &&
        in_array($this->response->type(), ['application/json', 'application/xml'])
    ) {
        $this->set('_serialize', true);
    }
}
```

In the controller from the second database, I have these functions:

```
public function initialize()
{

}

public function index()
{
    $connection = ConnectionManager::get('db3'); // 'db2' where my second database is configured 
    $machines = $connection->execute('SELECT * FROM MACHINE');

    $this->set(compact('machines'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['machines']);
}
```

After authentication, all models are working fine, except in this external view. I keep getting this error in machines index.ctp:

Here is the errors I get:

> App\Controller\AppController->beforeFilter
>    CORE\src\Event\EventManager.php, line 422
>       ⟩ Cake\Event\EventManager->_callListener
>       CORE\src\Event\EventManager.php, line 391
>       ⟩ Cake\Event\EventManager->dispatch
>       CORE\src\Event\EventDispatcherTrait.php, line 78
>       ⟩ Cake\Controller\Controller->dispatchEvent
>       CORE\src\Controller\Controller.php, line 497
>       ⟩ Cake\Controller\Controller->startupProcess
>       CORE\src\Http\ActionDispatcher.php, line 116
>       ⟩ Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher->_invoke
>       CORE\src\Http\ActionDispatcher.php, line 95
>       ⟩ Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher->dispatch
>       CORE\src\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 60
>       ⟩ Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->dispatch
>       ROOT\webroot\index.php, line 36
>
> Error in: ROOT\src\Controller\AppController.php, line 65
>   ( ! ) Xdebug: user triggered in C:\wamp64\www\inventory\src\Template\Error\error500.ctp on line 33
>   Call Stack
>
> ## Time    Memory  Function    Location
>
> 1 0.0861  5439240 Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler->wrapAndHandleException( )  ...\BaseErrorHandler.php:0
>   2 0.0888  5445696 Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler->handleException( ) ...\BaseErrorHandler.php:164
>   3 0.0888  5445696 Cake\Error\ErrorHandler->_displayException( )   ...\BaseErrorHandler.php:180
>   4 0.0919  5737712 Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer->render( ) ...\ErrorHandler.php:144
>   5 0.0932  5878816 Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer->_outputMessage( ) ...\ExceptionRenderer.php:194
>   6 0.1235  7711592 Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer->_outputMessage( ) ...\ExceptionRenderer.php:328
>   7 0.1235  7711592 Cake\Controller\Controller->render( )   ...\ExceptionRenderer.php:319
>   8 0.1255  7791592 Cake\View\View->render( )   ...\Controller.php:617
>   9 0.1260  7792544 Cake\View\View->_render( )  ...\View.php:597
>   10    0.1261  7793376 Cake\View\View->_evaluate( )    ...\View.php:973
>   11    0.1263  7822312 include( 'C:\wamp64\www\inventory\src\Template\Error\error500.ctp' )    ...\View.php:1014
>   12    0.1275  7840560 xdebug_print_function_stack ( ) ...\error500.ctp:33

What should I do exactly ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should tell us exactly where the error happens, preferably including a stack trace.

Comment: thanks Greg. I just added in my question

Comment: So, the error is at line 65 of your AppController. Which line is that?

Comment: the line 65 contains: $userId = $this->Auth->user('id');

Comment: What I understand is that the problem from using 2 databases: index.ctp is related to a table in the second databse, and the $userId is from a table in a the first database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second controller has an empty `initialize` function. As a result, the Auth component is not loaded (that's done by `AppController::initialize`, but it's never called), so when you try to use `$this->Auth` in `beforeFilter`, it doesn't exist. Is there a good reason why your second `initialize` is even there? Eliminate it, or else call `parent::initialize()` in it, either way would ensure that your required components are loaded.

Comment: Awsome. It works now! I tried deleting initialize and then adding parent::initialize(), and it works in both. Thanks alot Greg for your help!